# IOS Push Notifications for multiple Apps from one server

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We have 2 apps setup for Push Notifications. (A and B)

There are different profiles for each (of course) and we've generated separate certs for each.
App A receives Push notifications just fine, App B doesn't.

Both are talking to the same server - and it does figure out which app it's sending notifications to and uses the correct cert.

I've noticed that if you install both apps on one device, they both get the same Token (which our server tracks per app.).  When the server sends a msg in this case, it sends it twice to the same Token - once with each cert.  App A will receive the msg, App B won't.

When sending the msgs to both apps, the Apple server responds that all messages were sent correctly with no errors.  But the msg never shows up for the one app.

Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: If you send the B notifications first, does the B app receive and A app not?

Comment: XCode is definitely setup with different Profiles for each app, and both apps are currently in the store and working - except for Push notifications.  The Tokens are definitely identical.

Comment: A device setup with only App B will never receive a msg.  The server already sends to App B before App A.

Comment: @CasaDelGato Based on what you describe, the problem is either with the certificate of App B, or with the provisioning profile of App B (when you launch App B for the first time, are you asked whether to allow push notifications?)

Comment: @Eran - come to think of it, I don't think EITHER app has ever asked if I want to allow Push Notifications.  I've deleted them from the device multiple times.  Hmm, but in my case I'm always "installing" via build directly from Xcode.

Comment: Have you generating the APNS notification for both app with different certificates? Because, You can not use same PEM-File for multiple application. You would need to create separate PEM file for each application. So that apple push notification server(APNS) can identify your different applications by seperate PEM certificate.

Answer (score 3):

After much searching and looking, I found this question: [Iphone - Multiple Apps, Different App ID, Same Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594931/iphone-multiple-apps-different-app-id-same-token)

It points out that you must use a different .certSigningRequest for each app.  I checked with our AppStore guy, and he had used the same one for both certs.  He fixed that, and now it works!

Comment: Yes, you need to process private key as a p12 file to prepare pem file and this private key is generated in keychain app when you create a .certSigningRequest file. So, this CSR can be reused for same app upon expiration but a separate is needed for any other app. Time to accept your answer.