# How does Apple Generates Push Notification Token

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have been working on push notification for quite some time and have basic idea, how does it works. I am aware of the flow of push notification registration process and actual push notification delivery process.

As per my understanding Push Notification "Token" generated is unique per application / per device.

How ever, recently I was trying one of my old application for push notification with new "APP-ID" generated on new "Developer Account". Now my new Application, when I try to register for Push Notification, it returns me the same "Token" as it was returning for my old application.

Can any one justify any reason for above behaviour.

-- Vishal

Comment: Please [Read this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594931/iphone-multiple-apps-different-app-id-same-token), May be helpful for your confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

According to what I observed, until iOS7, all applications on the same device had the same device token (or, to be exact, they had one token for the development env and another for the production env). Therefore, that can explain what you observed.

I read (but never verified it myself) that starting in iOS7, each application on the same device would get a different device token.

Comment: Does it mean that even if I am testing two different applications with two different Developer Account Certificates, I may get same Token ? if my device is iOS 6 and before

Comment: @VishalKardode Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Thanks for the observations