# iOS Push Notification Assigning Same Token to Different Apps / Targets on Same Device

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that has multiple different Targets. Each Target has its own App Identifier (com.sample.app1, com.sample.app2 ...)

I am finding that when I install Ad Hoc / App Store versions of the different Targets on the same device, each Target is being assigned the same Push Notification Token. I can use this token in combination with each Target's Push Notification Certificate and it works correctly (pushes to the specified Target), but am I doing something incorrect? I had expected each Target to be assigned a different Push Notification Token.

Comment: The answer to your question can be found here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594931/iphone-multiple-apps-different-app-id-same-token

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338267/is-the-apn-device-token-unique-to-each-individual-app